# Add authentication before installing any apk in android

Tags: android

I need to know that is there any other app or source code in android who can restrict or authenticate before installing other apk. Means if some one knows device pattern and try to install any apk, before installing apk need to confirm with some password or pattern to go forward. Thanks

Comment: Are you asking if you can force a user to input a password or pattern before installing an app?

Comment: Yes before installing or uninstalling any app need to ask for password or pattern